# Is there any reason for a JFrame to not close after disposed statement?

Tags: java

One of my JFrame doesn't close after I implemented a dispose statement, this makes the program to open a new JFrame when the program is using the previously mention JFrame.

```
if (score.getStrikes() >= 3)
{
        score.setStrikes(0);
        score.setScore(0);
        GameOver.main(score);
        frmAnswer.dispose();
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell from your code example. Please add code that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your problem, which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show how the frame doesn't get close when using dispose.